# An alternative way for building a Unity project for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, build

For the last few days, I have been trying to build a testing project for android using the default build method but I just keep recieving errors and not knowing how to fix them.
[Short Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX9Ee.png)  and [Full Error Decscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abmtl.png). Also I am using Unity 5.6.7f1 with Admob plugins (And yes because my pc is shit so I use this version)
So I want to ask is there an alternative way for building an android app with Unity. I have heard about exporting the project to gradle and building it using Android Studio. But I don't know how.
If you know an alternative way or how to build the project with Android Studio or how to fix the error **PLEASE ANSWER**. I am having a nightmare with building this stupid test project to Android

Comment: The `dx` tool in your error message has been deprecated: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/the-path-to-dx-deprecation.html You may want to install an Android SDK from when your version of Unity was supported, but realize that if you intend to release to Google Play Store there is now a target SDK requirement: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your jdk(***1.8.0_311***) is too new to support legacy build command from Unity (***5.6.7f1***).

Two method to solve:

- **Install older jdk**

  if you don't know which version you should use. You may use the default jdk with Unity installer in *preferences*. (I'm not sure 5.6.7f1 is supported).

[image: default JDK]

- Export android project

  You can export android project by check the "*Export Project*". Then use android studio to build apk.

[image]